# How to correct my errors in my Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: python

I have a problem figuring out how to define rock and determine_winner I'm hoping someone could check out what I have and tell me were i'm going wrong. Also sometimes I get the program to run when I put it def main(): but it makes it spam in loop instead of hitting yes to play the game. Also am wondering if any of my indentations are wrong and if that could be the problem at hand.

```
import random
def process_computer_choice(): 

    return random.randint(1,3)

def process_player_choice():

    pass
def main():

    def computer_choice():
        return random.choice([1,2])
play_again = 'y'
number_of_tied_games = 0
number_of_player_games = 0
number_of_computer_games = 0
print("Let's play the game of rock, Paper, Scissors.")
while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':
        computer_choice=process_computer_choice()
        player_choice=process_player_choice()

        if computer_choice == 1: 
            print('the computer chooses rock.')
        elif computer_choice == 2: 
            print('the computer chooses paper.')
        else: 
            print('the computer chooses scissors.')
        #display player choice
        if player_choice == 1: 
            print('You choose rock.')
        elif player_choice == 2:
            print('You choose paper.')
        else: 
            print('You choose scissors.')

            result = determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice)
if results == 'computer':
            number_of_computer_games += 1
elif result == 'player':
            number_of_player_games += 1
else: 
            number_of_tied_games += 1
    
play_again = input('Do you want to play again? (Enter y for yes): ')
print('There were', number_of_tied_games, 'tie games played.')
print('The computer won', number_of_computer_games, 'game(s).')
print('You won', number_of_player_games, 'game(s).')
def process_computer_choice():  
    choice1 = random.randint(1, 3)


def process_player_choice():
        print('What is your choice? Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors: ',)
        choice2 = int(input())
        while choice2 != 1 and choice2 !=2 and choice2 != 3:
            print('ERROR: the choice can only be 1, 2 or 3.')
            choice2 = int(input("Please enter a correct choice:"))
        return choice2

def determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice):
        if coputer_choice == 1:
            if player_choice == 2:
                print('Paper covers rock. You wins!')
                winner = 'player'
        elif player_choice == 3:
             print('Rock crushes scissors. The computer wins!')
             winner = 'computer'
        else: 
             print('The game is tied. Try again.')
             winner = 'tied'
        if computer_choice == 2:
            if player_choice == 1:
                  print('Paper covers rock. The computer wins!')
                  winner = 'computer'
        elif player_choice == 3:
                print(' Scissors cuts paper.You win!')
                winner = 'player'
        else: 
                print('The game is tied. Try again.')
                winner = 'tied'
        if computer_choice == 3:
            if player_choice == 1:
                print('Rock smashes scissors. You win!')
                winner = 'player'
        elif player_choice == 2:
                print('Scissors cuts paper. The computer wins!')
                winner = 'computer'
        else: 
                print('The game is tied. Try again.')
                winner = 'tied'
        return winner
main()
```

Comment: Hi!
StackOverflow is not created for code reviews. Please, post your code review request on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @n0nvme CR is for improving working code, not fixing bugs.

Comment: Your indentation is totally messed up. Please post properly indented code.

Comment: Why do you have multiple definitions of `process_computer_choice()` and `process_player_choice()`?

Comment: Typo: `coputer_choice` should be `computer_choice`

Answer (score -1):

```
play_again = 'y'    # <- here's the issue
number_of_tied_games = 0
number_of_player_games = 0
number_of_computer_games = 0
print("Let's play the game of rock, Paper, Scissors.")
while play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':    # <-and here
```

You have to understand that a computer program goes top-down.
Meaning that if you put this particullar code outside of `main()` (or any function in general) this happens:

Essentially you assign the variable `play_again` the value 'y' and then the computer keeps on checking if the `play_again` is still y, which it is.
You can think of it as the computer completely ignoring the function until it's "called", meaning you do the thing you did at the end of the file "main()".

Comment: The line `play_again = input('Do you want to play again? (Enter y for yes): ')` needs to be indented so it's inside the loop.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know what "the issue" is here without the OP first fixing his indentation.  Sure, you're identifying why the code loops endlessly as is, but that's possibly due to bad indentation, not a conscious misunderstanding of the code on the OPs part.  The basic "play again" logic seems to be there such that it could work if the indentation were right.  There are likely multiple problems with this code.  We first have to see it formatted such that it is something worth looking at at all.

Comment: Hello i fixed indentation and it works it just wont let me play again unless I run it again.

Comment: It says results in line 43 not defined